# Github api 'List pull requests files' only returns 30 files

Tags: github, github-api, pull-request

I am trying to retrieve a list of all the files included in a pull request.
The Github API documentation in the following URL - https://developer.github.com/v3/pulls/#list-pull-requests-files mentions that it can retrieve a maximum of 300 files. However, when i run the request from Advanced Rest Client, i get a list of only 30 files.

Is there any way i could retrieve a list of all the files included in the pull request?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Github API paginates data in sets of 30 or 100 (depending on what you are requesting). You could consider increasing the `per_page` count to a higher value or just traverse through the pages. Ref: [Github Pagination](https://developer.github.com/v3/guides/traversing-with-pagination/)